# PYTHON: Fill nan values of df according to dict that comprises of Intervals | TypeError: unorderable types: Interval() < int()

Tags: python, pandas

The last statement returns: TypeError: unorderable types: Interval() < int()

```
j = pd.DataFrame({'a':[12,16,23,27,22,36,31,38], 'b':[np.nan, 23, 58, 
np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 76, np.nan]})

bin = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]

k = pd.cut(c.a, bin)

j['new'] = k

groupby = j.groupby('new').b.median()   #computation doesn't matter

dict = groupby.to_dict()

j['b'] = j['b'].fillna(j['new'].map(dict))
```

I have tried this using simple floats instead of intervals and it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it works nice, maybe need last version of pandas `0.20.2`:

```
j = pd.DataFrame({'a':[12,16,23,27,22,36,31,38], 
                  'b':[np.nan, 23, 58, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 76, np.nan]})

bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
j['new'] = pd.cut(j.a, bins)
print (j)
    a     b       new
0  12   NaN  (10, 20]
1  16  23.0  (10, 20]
2  23  58.0  (20, 30]
3  27   NaN  (20, 30]
4  22   NaN  (20, 30]
5  36   NaN  (30, 40]
6  31  76.0  (30, 40]
7  38   NaN  (30, 40]

d = j.groupby('new').b.median().to_dict()
print (d)
{Interval(30, 40, closed='right'): 76.0, 
 Interval(0, 10, closed='right'): nan, 
 Interval(10, 20, closed='right'): 23.0, 
 Interval(20, 30, closed='right'): 58.0}

j['b'] = j['b'].fillna(j['new'].map(d))
print (j)
    a     b       new
0  12  23.0  (10, 20]
1  16  23.0  (10, 20]
2  23  58.0  (20, 30]
3  27  58.0  (20, 30]
4  22  58.0  (20, 30]
5  36  76.0  (30, 40]
6  31  76.0  (30, 40]
7  38  76.0  (30, 40]
```

Simplier solution:

```
j['b'] = j.groupby(pd.cut(j.a, bins))['b'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
print (j)
    a     b
0  12  23.0
1  16  23.0
2  23  58.0
3  27  58.0
4  22  58.0
5  36  76.0
6  31  76.0
7  38  76.0
```

Comment: Oh no... I thought you changed something. It;s still giving me the same error. Do you have any idea why? @jezrael

Comment: In my opinion problem is in your pandas version, because `0.20.2` versions correct many bugs. So if one or second solution does not work, try upgrade if possible.

Comment: Supeeer, I was a bit surprised first solution works, because it is same as yours, only a bit improved. Good luck!

Comment: dude you are amazing. thank you so much I really really apreciate it! :) @jezrael

Comment: Sometimes. ;) Glad can help! I think [Interval](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-enhancements-intervalindex) is new thing, so maybe some bugs.

Comment: yeah probably so. I have pandas 0.20.2 by the way... so weird it's not giving you the same error as me @jezrael